# Redirect old domain urls to new one (except index.php and others)

Tags: php, redirect, url-rewriting

I have 2 domains: ok.com and ok.net
`ok.com` is my home page with 1 folder (`ok.com/test`)
`ok.net` is my store with products

I would like to make ok.com primary page with Home Page, and if type eg. `ok.com/product-2` then redirect to `ok.net/product-2`

Its working with

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://ok.net\/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but it redirects whole ok.com :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regular expression **(.*)$*** matches all uri string. If you just want to rewrite certain pages, for example, product- pages, you should try **(product.*)$**. Make sure the regular expression only match the pages needed to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

another option would be to [use Apache Virtual Hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html)